# Send email on SSH connection OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt

Is there a way to send an email when anyone connects via SSH (or LuCI for that matter)? I'm setting up my router to log to a flash drive so I guess I could grep the logs or possibly look at connections periodically with:

```
netstat -ntu | grep 22
```

but this feels more than clunky. Could I use: `cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack` somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it would be a good idea to do that via PAM, but you're on a router...
You could put something like

```
echo 'Root Shell Access | mail -s "Root Shell Access" your@yourdomain.com
```

in `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`, but then again that would fire every time you access your routers shell.

Better yet, modify or create /etc/ssh/sshrc with the following contents:

```
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $ip
echo "User $USER just logged in from $ip" | sendemail -q -u "SSH Login" -f "Originator <from@address.com>" -t "Your Name <your.email@domain.com>" -s smtp.server.com &
```

This will effectively notify you by email anytime someone logs in through SSH, and the login will be logged in the syslog.

```
Note: You'll need the `sendemail` package for the email notification to work.

Note: works with port forwarding, but with -N option not.
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful)

Comment: Thanks so much that works perfectly. The only change I made was to ssmtp as it seems like verizon doesn't support relay.